# Is it possible to revisit the 'Silent Realm' after completing a trial?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm running low on **Dusk Relics** and want to get more.  The **Silent Realms** are a good source for this rare treasure.

Would it be possible to revisit one of the **Silent Realms** after completing the trial so I may get more of these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth mentioning how exactly we may revisit the realm.  You can't go through the trial entrance like before, those are actually no longer available.

> After healing the **Thunder Dragon**, he'll recreate two different challenges for you, the **Boss Rush** mode which allows you to battle the first 8 previous bosses in the game or timed runs through the **Silent Realms**.  You can pick up and keep the **Dusk Relics** you find in the challenge.

Comment: Thanks for adding the specifics - I felt really bad that I couldn't find that information for you.

Answer (score 9):

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/61113993):

> Later during the game you will be able to revisit silent realms you've
>   completed.
>
> If you need the dusk relic treasure, there is a Sheikah Stone in a
>   cave in Skyloft (the first cave you go to find your Loftwing). There
>   should be a flock of butterflies there. Play your harp and a Sheikah
>   stone will emerge and will sell any treasure you want.
>
> Bring lots of money though, they're 100 Rupees each.

Comment: Oh good, but it's even better that I can buy the treasures, I have too much rupees.  :)

Comment: Yeah - I added that because although you weren't technically asking about the Dusk Relic specifically, it seemed like something you might want to know :)

Comment: It seems that stone is not available until much further in the game as the thread states.

Comment: Sorry Ashley, had to switch acceptance.  A "Yes" answer isn't has useful as a "Yes, here's how" answer.

Comment: @JeffMercado No worries, that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can redo Silent Realms at Lanayru (the Thunder Dragon).  Time Trials, but that doesn't mean you can't stop to pick up Dusk Relics too.  No need to buy them (or win them at Pumpkin Pull).