# When does the treasure merchant Sheikah Stone become available?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword* there is supposed to be a Sheikah Stone that sells treasure. [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38254/9300) tells where to find the stone, but says nothing about *when* it is available. How soon can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only access the **Moonlight Merchant** toward the end of the game after you completed the **Hero Song**.

At this point, the monsters will leave the **Waterfall Cave** completely and you will find the butterflies inside at night.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that crucial detail. :(

Answer (score 2):

The monsters only leave when you've made Batreaux human.  I'm not sure about the Song of the Hero - I think you need to have received the Stone of Trials first but I'm not sure.